# Locked by wait type OLEDB with SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server, excel, oledb

I have a batch process that generate one linked server over huge Excel files to fetch data into SQL Server 2012

Sometimes the process is locked by a wait type "OLEDB"

I can't find the root ause but my biggest problem is that I can't kill the process that has the wait_type OLEDB

I have try

```
KILL spid
```

Not works, never kill the spid.

SPID 90: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds.

```
ALTER DATABASE [DataMigration] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

But never finish (due PRINT_ROLLBACK_PROGRESS)

If I look into the process, I see the file that cause the block, but I don't know how solve the issue

```
SELECT * FROM SYSPROCESSES where spid=90
```

-There is any way to kill this process without restart the servers?
-How can avoid the wait type OLEDB? the same file in the same location usually works fine, the process hangs only some times.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple. `OLEDB` as a wait type often indicates some wait on another Server. This is also the reason why you can't kill the process. `OLEDB` is often (not always) used as a wait type for connections between SQL Server instances.

You kill the connection on your server, but if the process is running on another instance/linked server it will run there too. It will kill the process after the process on the other instance is finished.

So much to the bad news. The good news for you is, that you easily can find the query which runs on another linked server using this query:

```
SELECT spid, waitresource
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = <yourKilledSpid>
```

Just filter it for the spid you try to kill. The `waitresource` will indicate the remote server including the `spid` on the remote server. Go to the remote server and kill the `spid` there too. Your connection will immediately be killed/rolledback. Hopefully this solves your issue.

You can additionally try to take a look at the `waiting_tasks`. Maybe you'll see something helpful like a blocking resource in there.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
```

Comment: The linked server is a excel file. Remove the excel file not works. Remove the linked server also not works.

Comment: Did you get a waitresource anyway? You didn't mention anything. Does the import still proceeds? Do you see counting rows or something like that?

Comment: I get the waitresource from 
SELECT * FROM SYSPROCESSES where spid=90
Not looks like sitll procesing something, it's just lock.